Terrain and cloud correction for Sentinel-2
I want to filter out clouds and correct for terrain ruggedness in order to prep an image for a random forest model to create landclass raster files.
This is the code I wrote. When I run it, it seems very bright in some areas and the bands figures for RGB are much higher. Is this correct? "tioga" is the ROI
var tioga = WMU.filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('UNIT_NAME', 'TIOGA'));

// Harmonized Sentinel-2 Level 2A collection.
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED');

// Cloud Score+ image collection. Note Cloud Score+ is produced from Sentinel-2
// Level 1C data and can be applied to either L1C or L2A collections.
var csPlus = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/CLOUD_SCORE_PLUS/V1/S2_HARMONIZED');



// Use 'cs' or 'cs_cdf', depending on your use case; see docs for guidance.
var QA_BAND = 'cs_cdf';

// The threshold for masking; values between 0.50 and 0.65 generally work well.
// Higher values will remove thin clouds, haze & cirrus shadows.
var CLEAR_THRESHOLD = 0.65;

// Make a clear median composite.
var composite = s2
    .filterBounds(tioga)
    .filterDate('2022-05-01', '2022-06-01')
    .linkCollection(csPlus, [QA_BAND])
    .map(function(img) {
      return img.updateMask(img.select(QA_BAND).gte(CLEAR_THRESHOLD));
    })
    .median();

// Sentinel-2 visualization parameters.
var s2Viz = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 2500};

Map.addLayer(composite, s2Viz, 'median composite');
Map.centerObject(tioga, 9);
Map.addLayer(tioga, null, "Tioga_WMU", false);//add the tioga wmu

print(composite, 'median composite')

//FUNCTION TO CONVERT DEGREES TO RADIANS
function toRadians(img) {
  return img.toFloat().multiply(Math.PI).divide(180)}
  

var dem = ee.Image('USGS/3DEP/10m').clip(tioga);
var shade = ee.Terrain.hillshade(dem)
var SLP = toRadians(ee.Terrain.slope(dem))
var ASP = toRadians(ee.Terrain.aspect(dem))
Map.addLayer(shade,{},'shade')


var s2q = s2
    .filterBounds(tioga)
    .filterDate('2022-05-01', '2022-06-01')
    .sort('CCLOUDY_PIXEL_OVER_LAND_PERCENTAGE')
    .first()
print(s2q)

//COLLECT VARIABLES FROM IMAGE METADATA
var AZ = ee.Number(s2q.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE'))
print(AZ, "AZ")
//solar_azimuth_angle
var ZE = ee.Number(s2q.get('MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE')) //solar_zenith_angle
var AZ_R = toRadians(ee.Image(AZ))
var ZE_R = toRadians(ee.Image(ZE))

//CALCULATE ILLUMINATION CONDITIONS AND COSINE OF THE ZENITH ANGLE
var IC = AZ_R.subtract(ASP).cos().multiply(SLP.sin()).multiply(ZE_R.sin())
.add(ZE_R.cos().multiply(SLP.cos()))
Map.addLayer(IC, {},'illumination conditions')

//APPLY COSINE CORRECTION
var cos_ZE = ZE_R.cos()
var tioga_corrected = composite.multiply(cos_ZE).divide(IC)


Map.addLayer(tioga_corrected,s2Viz,'corrected')

